Stripper falls for a tourist and opens an espresso bar
Hey im trying to find the name of a movie. The plot points I remember.
A guy travels out of town and ends up at a strip club drunk. When he gets ina  taxi to leave and has no money, this stripper lets him go home with her and makes him sleep on the couch.
The stripper loves to cook and the guy is an accountant. They become good friends.
The stripper and the guy fall in love, kindof, and the guys ex-girlfriend shows up and he leaves the stripper for her.
The guy ends up breaking up with his girlfriend and gets the stripper a loan to start her business.
Any help is appreciated.

Can you tell us what year or at least decade you believe/know the movie was released in? Do you know if it was a feature film, or made for TV? Any other details to help narrow it down would be great.

i know i watched it in 2012. The guy visits toronto. It was in theaters i believe?

Could you be thinking of My Awkward Sexual Adventure (2012)? I can't find much information about the plot but it's a Canadian comedy which fits with it being set in Toronto, IMDb says:

To win back his ex-girlfriend, a conservative accountant enlists the help of an exotic dancer to guide him on a quest for sexual experience, leading him into a world of strip clubs, sensual massage parlors, cross-dressing and S & M.


thats it man, thanks alot. couldnt think of the name
